# readxl: read numeric column labels (wide data)

Tags: r, readxl

I am using readxl to read an Excel file in the R tidyverse. It is a wide data set, i.e. with years being column labels (e.g. 2010, 2015 etc.).

The labels are interpreted as numeric by readxl, and the df column labels are now called 2010.0, 2015.0 etc.. How can I tell readxl to "keep as is", and have labels "2010", "2015" etc.?

```
df <- readxl::read_excel("Population-SSP1-Countries.xlsx", col_names = TRUE)

head(df)
> # A tibble: 6 x 25`
> Model Scenario Region Variable Unit   `2010.0` `2015.0` `2020.0` `2025.0` `2030.0`
> <chr> <chr>    <chr>  <chr>    <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
> 1 IIAS… SSP1     ABW    Populat… mill…    0.107    0.118    0.124    0.130    0.135`
> 2 NCAR  SSP1     ABW    Populat… mill…    0.107    0.118    0.124    0.130    0.135
> 3 OECD… SSP1     ABW    Populat… mill…    0.107    0.118    0.124    0.13     0.135`
```

I can provide the fitting .xlsx, not sure how to upload this here.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe just rename the column names?

Comment: A possibility I have used in the past, but makes code not very versatile and long for data sets with many columns.
I am wondering I seem to be the first who stumbles over this?

Comment: Looks like a known issue, still open, see https://community.rstudio.com/t/readxl-changing-my-column-headers/1858  and https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/360

Comment: Thanks, after reading the first post (community.rstudio.com/t/readxl-changing-my-column-headers/1858) I realize it is an issue that Ecel has a cell type "Number" for the column header. Changing this to "Text" in Excel removes the issue with readxls. May also explain why Paul wasn't able to reproduce this.

Comment: @Steffen maybe post your comment as an answer to your own question, it might help future readers :)

Answer (score 2):

an option would be to rename the column names:

```
library(stringr)
names(df) <- stringr::str_remove(colnames(df), "\\.0")
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a useful hint for post-processing!

Answer (score 1):

After reading
[community.rstudio.com/t/readxl-changing-my-column-headers/1858](http://community.rstudio.com/t/readxl-changing-my-column-headers/1858)

I realize it is an issue that Ecel has a cell type "Number" for the column header. Changing the cell type to "Text" in Excel for the column labels removes the issue with readxls.